# How to get tag value and replace tags in html code stored in table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a pieces of html code stored in table, and I need to replace some specific tags.

```
<br><pws:img num="10956">Pic001</psw:img><br><br><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="696" style="color: #000000; font-family: -webkit-standard; border-collapse: collapse; width: 522pt; border: 1px dashed #AAAAAA;" prevstyle="color: #000000; font-family: -webkit-standard; border-collapse: collapse; width: 522pt; border: 1px dashed #AAAAAA;"><tr><td><pws:img num="10201">Pic002</psw:img></td></tr></table>
```

All occurances of `pws:img` tag I need to replace with `<img src="files/NUM" alt="TEXT">`
where NUM is num attribute value from `pws:img` tag (10956 in 1st occurance, 10201 in 2nd occurance), and TEXT is a string (Pic001 in 1st occurance)

So 1st occurance `<pws:img num="10956">Pic001</psw:img>` shoud be replaced by `<img src="files/10956" alt="Pic001">`

I made function with for cycle and regexp_replace/ regexp_substr, but not working. Thx for help

Comment: You have opening `pws:img` tags and closing `psw:img` tags; one of these is probably a typo.

Answer (score 1):

In general, don't use regular expressions to parse XML/HTML; however, if you can guarantee that there will be no nested elements within the `pws:img` tag then you could use something like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( html ) AS
SELECT '<br><pws:img num="10956">Pic001</pws:img><br><br><table><tr><td><pws:img num="10201">Pic002</pws:img></td></tr></table>'
FROM   DUAL
```

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE( html, '<pws:img\s+([^>"]|".*?")*num\s*=\s*("(\d+)"|(\d+))([^>"]|".*?")*>.*?</pws:img>', '<img src="files/\3\4" alt="TEXT" />') AS replaced_html
FROM   test_data
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> | REPLACED_HTML                                                                                                         |
> | :-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | <br><img src="files/10956" alt="TEXT" /><br><br><table><tr><td><img src="files/10201" alt="TEXT" /></td></tr></table> |
> ```

You can also do it with a FLOWR expression (if you can get your HTML snippet to be a valid XHTML document):

```sql
SELECT XMLQUERY(
         'copy $NEWHTML := .
         modify (
           for $i in $NEWHTML/body//pws_img
           return replace node $i with <img num="{$i/@num}" alt="TEXT" />
         )
         return $NEWHTML/body/*'
         PASSING XMLTYPE(
           '<body>'
           || REPLACE( REPLACE( html, '<br>', '<br />' ), 'pws:img', 'pws_img' )
           || '</body>'
         )
         RETURNING CONTENT
       ).getStringVal() AS replacement_html
FROM   test_data
```

which outputs:

> ```
> | REPLACEMENT_HTML                                                                                           |
> | :--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | <br/><img num="10956" alt="TEXT"/><br/><br/><table><tr><td><img num="10201" alt="TEXT"/></td></tr></table> |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7764051a0cf027eb529634eee1a943b6)*